# Class names concatenated or separated by a space

Tags: css

When do you separate style classes with a space? So for example: what is the difference between the following two blocks of css?

**Block 1**:

```css
div {
    color: brown;
}

div.special {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

**Block 2**:

```css
div {
    color: brown;
}

div .special {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="special">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</div>
```

I tried both versions. Only with block 1 the text wil be in font size 18.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You separate classes by a space when you want to refer to descendant element and you concatenate them when you want to refer to a single element with multiple classes.

For example, to refer to  a div with two classes, e.g. `<div class="foo bar">` you could use:

```
div.foo.bar {...}
```

To refer to the child span element `<div class="foo"><span class="bar">stuff</span></div>` you could use:

```
div.foo .bar {...}
```

Comment: I might say "one or more classes" instead of "multiple," but other than that this is a nice, succinct reply!

Answer (score 36):

A space indicates nesting:

```
div .foo /* .foo is inside div */
```

No space indicates further specificity:

```
div.foo /* any div that is also .foo */
```

Answer (score 7):

`div.special` refers to

```
<div class="special"> <- this
```

`div .special` refers to

```
<div>
    <p class="special"> <-  this
</div>
```

Not neccassily a `p` BTW

Answer (score 3):

The space notes that this is a child item.

IE

```
div.special
```

targets a div that has the class `special` while

```
div .special
```

targets an element with class `special` inside a `div` element

Answer (score 1):

`div.special` will select the `div` element which has class `.special` and it wont select any other element with class `.special` so if you have something like `<ul class="special">` will be excluded, where as this `div .special` will select all the elements having class `.special` which are nested inside `div` so this will select `<ul class="special">` so it concludes that the 1st one is stricter than the second one

So in your case either you can simply use `.special` or you can use `div.special`